# Sqoop import not working with hive parquet

Tags: import, hive, sqoop, parquet, cdc

Change data capture in Sqoop-Hive Import

I am trying to do change data capture using Sqoop but when I am writing -as-parquet I my Sqoop import command it is falling .but after removing -as-parquet from my Sqoop command it is working and putting data in text format in hive table but want it in parquet hive table.

i want to do update operation from my data.

Comment: can you provide more context? Show the command and the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this below command :

```
Sqoop import --connect "myoracleconntiondetails" 
             --username myuser --password mypasswd 
             --query 'select * from test_table where $CONDITIONS' 
             --hive_import --hive-database test_dase 
             --hive-table test_dase.test_table --null-string 'NULL' 
             --null-non-string '-99999' --target-dir mydir/full path 
             --split-by mycol --incremental append 
             --merge-key could -as-parquet -m -10
```

I get this error:

> Got exception running sqoop: org.kitesdk.data.validationException: Dataset name test_dase.test_table is not alphanumeric (plus '*')
> Org.kitesdk.data.validation:Dataset name test_dase.test_table is not alphanumeric (plus '*')

Comment: You can try replacing `test_pase.test_table` with `test_dase_test_table`